# Composite Primary Key with 4 attributes

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I would like to have a `DRINKS` table with the following attributes:

- d_Brand (e.g. Staropramen )
- d_Type (e.g. Lager )
- d_Size (e.g. 0,5 l )
- d_Wrapping ( can/glass)
- d_Stock (yes/no)
- d_Price (number)

I don't want to work with a single `PRIMARY KEY`, like a `DRINK_ID`. I would like to create a composite `PRIMARY KEY` with multiple attributes( basically 4). One drink could be identified by the brand, type, size and wrapping together.

I've tried to create it but I had a "character string buffer too small" error, using `VARCHAR`.

```
CONSTRAINT d_DRINK PRIMARY KEY(d_Size, d_Wrapping, d_Stock, d_Price)
```

Can someone help me create it properly?

Comment: The `sql-server` tag is for *Microsoft SQL Server*. Googling that error message indicates you're using `oracle`, so I replaced the tag.

Comment: What are the actual data types of the columns, including the data lengths?  It would probably be easiest and best to edit your question and post the SQL query you're running that is generating the error.

Comment: That's a PL/SQL error message. It's not clear how you would get that when issuing a CREATE TABLE statement. Please post the actual code you're running. If you want us to help you need to provide all the information.

Answer (score 0):

first, just create table DRINKS without PK.

then go and run the following statement:

alter table DRINKS add constraint MY_PK primary key(d_Size, d_Wrapping, d_Stock, d_Price);